# Let F be a field of order 32. Show that the only subfields of F are F itself and {0,1}.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

$F$ is a field of order $32$.
$F$ and {$0,1$} are trivial subfields of $F$.

But how can we show that these are the only subfields of $F$?
Can someone give me a direction to this question?

Comment: Do you remember what happens to degrees of field extensions in a tower? Say if $K\subset L\subset F$ are fields, then $[F:K]$ is the _______ of $[F:L]$ and $[L:K]$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hint: if $K$ is a subfield of $F$, then in particular, $K^*$, the multiplicative group of $K$ must be a subgroup of $F^*$

Comment: so that means order of F* is 31 (prime number) and it can have just two subgroups with respect to multiplication - F* and {1}.

Comment: Nice observation, but it wouldn't work for a field with $ 2^{11}$ elements because $2^{11}-1$ is not prime.

Comment: thus F can have only two subfields F and {0,1}

Comment: @ShreyaTaneja - that's exactly right.

Comment: @Ihf - agreed. And your answer is definitely the more general solution!

Comment: @user1952009, I'm not sure what you're asking. Perhaps you could ask a separate question.

Comment: @lhf $2^{11}-1= 23 \times 89$ is the first composite Mersenne number. If $G \vartriangleleft \mathbb{F}_{2^{11}}^\times$ is a subgroup $|G|=23$. Do you know if $G$ has some special properties, what is the smallest ring containing it .. ? More generally, what is special with those field $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ such that $2^n-1$ is prime ?

Comment: @user1952009 well for one, since $G$ a finite multiplicative subgroup of a field, it is cyclic. I'm not sure what more you really want.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Yes of course, I really meant what lhf remarked : has the primality/compositeness of $2^n-1$ some other remarkable effects on the structure of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ ? (it seems obvious yes)

Comment: @user1952009 you could say the same thing with $\mathbb F_3$ vs $\mathbb F_9$. I'm really not sure there's much to it. As multiplicative groups both are cyclic, although one is of prime order. As fields, their structure is similar. I'd be very interested to see an example of a concrete difference though.

Answer (score 20):

More generally, a field with $p^n$ elements contains a subfield with $p^m$ elements iff $m$ divides $n$.

In your case, we have $p=2$ and $n=5$, which has no nontrivial divisors.

Here is a proof of one direction, the one that concerns the question:

If a field $F$ has $p^n$ elements and contains a subfield $K$ with $p^m$ elements, then $F$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $K$ and so $p^n=(p^m)^d=p^{md}$, where $d$ is the dimension of $F$ over $K$.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a field $F$ of order $p^n$, $p$ is a prime & $n$ is a positive integer, then for each divisor $m$ of $n$ there is a unique subfield of order $p^m$. These are the only subfields of $F$.
Now, we have $32=2^5$. The divisors of $5$ are $1,5$. So there are only two subfields, one is of order $2^1$ and another is of order $2^5$. And hence the only subfields are {0,1} and the field itself.